# Roots of a polynomial inside a unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $h(z) = z^7 - 5z^4+z^2 - 2$. I have to find a number of roots inside a unit circle $|z|<1$. Using 
Rouché's theorem I've tried:

$g(z) = z^7 + z^2 - 2$

$f(z) = -5z^4$

Then $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on the unit circle and $f(z)$ has $4$ roots inside the circle, and then so has $h(z)$.
Am I correct?

Comment: Seems correct. $|g(z)|\leq 4<5=|f(z)|$ when $|z|=1$.